# How do I automate chains of map lookups in F#?

Tags: types, dictionary, f#, monads

I regularly have cause to lookup some key in a map and then lookup the result in another map and so on in an arbitrary chain and am seeking to generalise the process. I also want to be able pre-compute lists of maps for this purpose to represent re-usable chains of association in an AI project.

The obvious solution seems to be a simple extension of a map function over lists that I call “maybe_map”.

```
let rec maybe_map operation initial_value list =
  match list with
  | []          -> Some(initial_value)
  | first::rest ->
    match operation initial_value first with
    | None                   -> None
    | Some(subsequent_value) -> maybe_map operation subsequent_value rest
```

The following is an example of its use.

```
let employee_department = Map.ofList([("John", "Sales" ); ("Bob",    "IT"    )])
let department_country  = Map.ofList([("IT",   "USA"   ); ("Sales",  "France")])
let country_currency    = Map.ofList([("USA",  "Dollar"); ("France", "Euro"  )])

let result = maybe_map Map.tryFind "John" [employee_department; department_country; country_currency]
```

This works fine and yields the result Some(“Euro”). The problem comes when I need to use data in which the domain and range types of the maps differ. For example if I add an exchange rate map to the above example the type checker complains even though none of the individual operations involved would fail.

```
let exchange_rate = Map.ofList([("Euro", 1.08); ("Dollar", 1.2)])

let result1 = maybe_map Map.tryFind "John" [employee_department; department_country; country_currency; exchange_rate]
```

The type checker complains that exchange_rate is expected to be of type Map<string,string> despite the fact that the following applications of Map.tryFind are both valid.

```
let result2 = Map.tryFind "John" employee_department
let result3 = Map.tryFind "Euro" exchange_rate
```

If I were doing this in C# it seems that it would be relatively straightforward to define maybe_map over over data of type Dictionary<IComparable, IComparable> and clearly any “Duck Typed” language would have no problem, but I cannot see how to do this in F#.

A reference to solving this kind of problem that seems to come up quite often is http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/01/28/much-ado-about-monads-maybe-edition/ which follows an approach based on monads. In fact, the data used in the examples here are taken from this article. However, despite the fact that using monads to do something this simple seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, the solution given in the article also breaks down when the domain and range types of the maps differ.

Does anyone know how I can make progress with this without introducing significant extra complexity to what seems conceptually very straightforward?

**Epilog**

After considering the very helpful input received as a result of this question, this is what we decided to go with.

```
class chainable
{
  protected Dictionary<IComparable, IComparable> items = new Dictionary<IComparable,IComparable>();

  public chainable() {}

  public chainable(params pair[] pairs) { foreach (pair p in pairs) items.Add(p.key, p.value); }

  public void add(IComparable key, IComparable value) { items.Add(key, value); }

  public IComparable lookup(IComparable key) { if (items.ContainsKey(key)) return items[key]; else return null; }

  public static List<chainable> chain(params chainable[] chainables) { return new List<chainable>(chainables); }

  public static IComparable lookup(IComparable key, List<chainable> chain)
  {
    IComparable value = key;
    foreach (chainable link in chain) { value = link.lookup(value); if (value == null) return null; }
    return value;
  }
}
```

The first line of this class is virtually a specification of what is required and the rest of the operations follow straightforwardly from it.

```
chainable employee_department = new chainable(new pair("John", "Sales" ), new pair("Bob",    "IT"    ));
chainable department_country  = new chainable(new pair("IT",   "USA"   ), new pair("Sales",  "France"));
chainable country_currency    = new chainable(new pair("USA",  "Dollar"), new pair("France", "Euro"  ));
chainable exchange_rate       = new chainable(new pair("Euro", 1.08    ), new pair("Dollar", 1.2     ));
List<chainable> chain = chainable.chain(employee_department, department_country, country_currency, exchange_rate);
IComparable result    = chainable.lookup("John", chain);
```

Admittedly the chainable class could be constructed in F#, but that would just be writing C# using F# syntax so we have decided to cut-out the middle man. It seems that F# is not always able to infer the type of the data you really needed to operate on from a straightforward description of the operations required. Thanks again for the help (Sorry, but using Haskell  was not an option).

Comment: Does your design have to be so much about strings and dictionaries? Couldn't department be an object that references the country object?

Comment: @svick Unfortunately the arbitrary "things" involved in mappings are not known before the system runs.

Comment: I wasn't expecting you to move to Haskell :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using this helper function

```
let search map = Option.bind (fun k -> Map.tryFind k map)
```

you could chain together the maps being searched using function composition:

```
let searchAll = 
  search employee_department
  >> search department_country
  >> search country_currency
  >> search exchange_rate

searchAll (Some "John") //Some 1.08
```

This ensures that the type of the value of map `N` matches the type of the key of map `N+1`. I don't see a way of searching a `list<Map<_,_>>` without resorting to some interface (like `IDictionary`) and inserting calls to `box`/`unbox` to sidestep the type system.

Incidentally, your `maybe_map` function could be written

```
let maybeMap = List.fold (fun v m -> Option.bind (fun k -> Map.tryFind k m) v)
```

(which still doesn't work for `Map`s of different types)

**EDIT**

Since your maps aren't defined at compile time, and differ by type args, you could instead build a collection of lookup functions at run-time.

```
let maybeMap = Seq.fold (fun v f -> Option.bind f v)
let tryFind m (v: obj) = Map.tryFind (unbox v) m |> Option.map box

let lookups = ResizeArray() //using ResizeArray to emphasize that this is built dynamically
lookups.Add(tryFind employee_department)
lookups.Add(tryFind department_country)
lookups.Add(tryFind country_currency)
lookups.Add(tryFind exchange_rate)

maybeMap (Some (box "John")) lookups
```

It's not as tidy, but meets your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes that does the job but, as you say, unfortunately still doesn't support lists of maps, which is key. I "unwound" my maybe_map function from a version using List.fold to try and find scope for introducing type constraints to solve the problem and to make it easier to talk about. I'm beginning to think that the root of this problem is finding a way of constructing lists containing maps of different types in the first place.

Comment: You could construct a list of functions instead of maps. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Yes. Of course, when in doubt add an extra layer of functions! (kicks self for not thinking of this) I am marking this as answered as I can see how I can adapt your solution to my needs. However it is still a little bit disappointing that the type checking makes one work so hard sometime to do conceptually simple things. I get the impression it is not able to infer common subtypes, which is what I was trying to make it do.

Comment: In a hypothetical scenario, if you have map #1 `<string,float>`, #2 `<float,int>`, and #3 `<int,string>`, you could chain successive calls to `Map.tryFind` using function composition, but I don't see how a common base type could be determined for a list of those maps (other than `obj`, similar to my example). In theory, you could have a `list<Map<IComparable, IComparable>>` but I'm not sure it provides any benefit in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniel has given a brilliant solution. I want to comment on what can and cannot be done with generics: The original program is *obviously* type safe, so why doesn't the compiler realise that?

Here are the critical bits (paraphrasing):

```
let country_currency = Map.ofList([("USA",  "Dollar"); ("France", "Euro")])
let exchange_rate    = Map.ofList([("Euro", 1.08); ("Dollar", 1.2)])
let maps = [country_currency; exchange_rate]
// Error: "... Expecting a Map<string,string> but given a Map<string,float>"
```

Well, F# lists are homogenous: they can contain only values of the same type (objects and casting not withstanding). But we want different types `Map<..., string>` and `Map<string, float>`, so we can't put chains of maps in lists. We don't really care need a list, though, we just want some collection of maps where the value-type of one is the key-type of the next. Let's try to make such a type.

```
type Chain<'T,'U> =
    | Link of Chain<'T,'R> * Chain<'R,'U>
    | Node of Map<'T,'U>
```

The compiler won't let us, though:

> error FS0039: The type parameter 'R' is not defined

Ideally, we'd like the `Link` constructor to be generic in `'R`, i.e., to write something
like this:

```
    | Link<'R> of Chain<'T,'R> * Chain<'R,'U>
```

But this is also not allowed: All type parameters used to define `type Chain<...>` must be declared in the `<...>`. Objects and casting not withstanding, this means that *a value of an F# type can be composed of only a fixed number of other types*. But we don't know how many different types of Map we need to chain!

---

Let's say F# *did* allow `Link` to be generic independently of `Chain`. Then patten matching allows the type parameter `'R` to escape:

```
match c : Chain<string, float> with 
| Link (c1, c2) -> ... // c1 : Map<string, 'R>,  c2 : Map<'R, float> ?
```

Of course, the `c` was constructed somehow by some *actual* type instead of the type parameter `'R`, but we don't know which. In this case, we say that `c1` and `c2` have "existential type": We know there "exists" some particular type we can put in for `'R` above, but we don't know which. If we had such existential types, we could write the requested `maybe_map`:

```
// maybe_map<'T,'U> : 'T -> Chain<'T,'U> -> Option<'U> 
let rec maybe_map k = function
   | Node m -> Map.tryFind k m
   | Link (c1, c2) ->            // some 'R. c1: Map<'T,'R>, c2: Map<'R,'U>
        let o = maybe_map k c1   // o : ?'R option 
        match o with                
        | None -> None 
        | Some v -> maybe_map v c2   // : Option<'U>
```

We don't get to do this in F#, but [the Haskell people do](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type). Let's see the entire thing in Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

department_country = Map.fromList [("IT",   "USA"   ), ("Sales",  "France")]
country_currency   = Map.fromList [("USA",  "Dollar"), ("France", "Euro")]
exchange_rate      = Map.fromList [("Euro", 1.08),     ("Dollar", 1.2)]

data Chain t u =
    forall r. (Ord r) =>   -- Any type r can be inside the chain
       Link (Chain t r) (Chain r u)
  | Node (Map t u)

lookup :: (Ord t, Ord u) => t -> Chain t u -> Maybe u
lookup k (Node m) = Map.lookup k m
lookup k (Link c1 c2) = case lookup k c1 of
                           Just v -> lookup v c2
                           Nothing -> Nothing

chain = Link (Node department_country) 
             (Link (Node country_currency) (Node exchange_rate))
```

And try it out:

```
*Main> maybe_map "IT" chain
Just 1.2
```